# How can I see how long an EBS snapshot took?

Tags: amazon-ebs, snapshot

I'm trying to do some planning and have been experimenting with EBS snapshots for data backups. I want to see how long a snapshot took of a 50G volume, but I only see the start time, not the completion time under the "Description" tag in AWS console. Is there a way to find out this information 'after the fact'?

Comment: yes its shows only the start time, you can monitor time manually by taking a manual snapshot

Answer (score 0):

While the only way to see how long a snapshot takes is as @Vijay Muddu has mentioned (by manually starting it and monitoring the status), there may be some additional information that will assist.

**EBS Snapshots are Incremental**

This means that once the first snapshot has been completed, the second snapshot will only contain the blocks that have changed. AWS keeps track of which blocks need to be retained, so you can delete the first snapshot without having to worry.

**EBS Snapshots are Point-in-Time**

Once you initiate a snapshot it is created immediately, but the snapshot is shown as pending until all of the modified blocks have been transferred to S3. So any changes that occur after you initiated the snapshot will not affect the snapshot.

**Some Instance Types Allow Multiple Concurrent Snapshots**

You can create a new snapshot while there is already one pending.

> There is a limit of five pending snapshots for a single gp2, io1, or Magnetic volume, and one pending snapshot for a single st1 or sc1 volume.

There's more information in the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html).

Comment: Thanks - didn’t know you could have multiple simultaneous snapshots going. However I also understand that time taken can depend on time of day - based on load on the EBS infrastructure etc

Comment: How frequently is your data changing? With the incremental nature of snapshots, if you take them frequently they should complete relatively quickly. I can't speak to the time of day comment, but it does sound plausible.

Comment: The EBS volumes form a RAID storing a high volume MongoDB database with random writes which likely touch a lot of different blocks in a short time.